# Using Selectize.js doesnot trigger asp.net core client side validation for the select list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, selectize.js

Selectize.js not triggering client side validation on .net core 2.2

I want to handle automatic client side validation via  asp.net core's model property binding.

```
public class Person{
[Required]
public string PersonName{get;set;}

[Required]
public string GenderId{get;set;}
}


<form asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Create" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="PersonName"></label>
         <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
           <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="GenderId"></label>
           select class="customDropdown form-control" asp-for="GenderId"asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.GenderList, "ListItemId","ListItemName"))">
             <option value="">Select...</option>
         </select>
<span asp-validation-for="GenderId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
         </div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
@section Scripts{

<script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js">
```

```
<script>

    $(function () {
    $('.customDropdown ').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text'
    });
```

});

```
</script>
```

The validation works for the select List  if I don't use selectize.js.

Comment: did you find a solution? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo to reproduce the issue, but validation worked well when using the selectize.js.  Check if the path of the two referenced js files is correct .The following is the path of which js files I reference:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js">
```

Comment: The validation works for other input fields but not for the select list that uses selectize.js